# How can I get the max of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

my goal is to get the max of two lists,
for instance :
list a -[1,2,3]
list b - [0,4,1]

the desire resuls: 1,4,3
[image]

def ddh(a,b):
v=[]

```
for i,j in range(len(a),len(b)):
    
    if a[i]>b[j]:
         v.append (a[i])
   
    else:
         v.append (b[j])
              
return v
```

a=[1,2,555,9999]
b=[22,4,444]
ddh(a,b)

I tried to run the code and got just []

Comment: consider carefully what is going on here: `for i,j in range(len(a),len(b))`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension  to iterate over the 2 lists at the same time using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and take the max of every iteration:

```py
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [0, 4, 1]

maxes = [max(a, b) for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
# [1, 4, 3]
```

You don't even need to unpack the tuple:

```py
maxes = [max(values) for values in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

And with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for a more functional approach:

```py
maxes = list(map(max, zip(list_a, list_b)))
```

Comment: I tried :
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [0, 4, 1]
def hhhs(makes):
    maxes = [max(a, b) for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
    
     
    
       

hhhs(makes)
and got :
NameError: name 'makes' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
max_zip = [max(a_, b_) for a_, b_ in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(a,b):
    return [a if a>b else b for a,b in zip(a,b)]

print(func([1,2,3],[0,4,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter and optimal version of your function.

```py
def ddh(a,b):
    return [max(a[i],b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]

a=[1,2,3]
b=[0,4,1]
print (ddh(a,b))
```